# UITabbarController setting view

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, ios4

I have a UITabbarController set by the Interfacebuilder.
The tabbarcontroller has 5 tabs, the first is a welcome page, and the second is a UITableViewController. Both have a NavigationController. The 2nd tab should show a category list.
When I launch the app, all is fine. When I press the 2nd tab, it load the view perfectly with the navigation controller.
But what I want to do is to be able to load a certain category in the 2nd tab using a link in the first tab.

So what I did was I added the following function in my appDelegate and call is from the view in my first tab:

```
- (void)loadCategoryViewUsingCategoryId:(NSString*)categoryId
{
    CategoryViewController *categoryView = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithLoadingCategoryUsingCategoryId:categoryId];

    if (!categoryView) {
        UIAlertView *errorView;
        errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Whoops", @"oddsAppAppDelegate")
                     message: NSLocalizedString(@"I did not found the requested category. Sorry!", @"oddsAppAppDelegate")
                     delegate: self
                     cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"oddsAppAppDelegate") otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorView show];
        [errorView autorelease];
    }
    else {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = categoryView;
        [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController setTitle:@"apa"];
        [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, BUT... when the 2nd tab is loaded it doesn't have the navigation controller toolbar. How can I load it so I keep my navigation controller toolbar?

The "`CategoryViewController`" is a `UITableViewController` by the way.

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigation Bar shall be visible by default. If you want to access it directly with

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

I think your problem is somewhere else. If you assign your controllers like this

```
UITabBarController *theTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
YourWelcomeViewClassHere *welcome = [[YourWelcomeViewClassHere alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourWelcomeViewClassHere" bundle:nil]; //Or other custom initalizers
UINavigationController *welcomeNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcome];
CategoryViewController *category = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:nil]; //Or other custom initalizers
UINavigationController *categoryNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:category];
/*
Your other View controllers initializations
*/

NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:welcomeNav,categoryNav,/* other viewControllers ,*/nil];
[theTabBar setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

This might work and show your views.

Comment: Hi,

I tried that, but it doesn't really work for me. Then again, your post started me thinking and gave me the following solution:
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

  UINavigationController *nav = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
  nav.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:categoryView, nil];

This worked for me. 
Regards,
Paul Peelen